# Reading/writing files to/from a struct/class

Tags: c++, class, struct, ifstream, ofstream

I'd like to read a file into a struct or class, but after some reading i've gathered that its not a good idea to do something like:

```
int MyClass::loadFile( const char *filePath ) {

            ifstream file ( filePath, ios::in | ios::binary );

            file.read ((char*)this, 18);

            file.close();

            return 0;

        }
```

I'm guessing if i want to write a file from a struct/class this isn't kosher either:

```
void MyClass::writeFile( string fileName ) {

        ofstream file( fileName, ofstream::binary ); 

        file.write((char*)this, 18);

        file.close();

    }
```

It sounds like the reason i don't want to do this is because even if the data members of my struct add up to 18 bytes, some of them may be padded with extra bytes in memory. Is there a more correct/elegant way to get a file into a class/struct like this?

Comment: The only real solution is to write the individual fields one by one. Mind endianness, or even better, transform each field to a humanly-readable representation (eg. number 42 yields the string "42") before writing it, so that your file can be manually edited in a standard text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred general technique is called serialization.

It is less brittle than a binary representation. But it has the overhead of needing to be interpreted. The standard types work well with serialization and you are encouraged to make your class serialize so that a class containing your class can easily be serialized.

```
class MyClass {
     int x;
     float y;
     double z;
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MyClass const& data);
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, MyClass& data);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MyClass const& data)
{
    // Something like this
    // Be careful with strings (the input>> and output << are not symmetric unlike other types)
    return str << data.x << " " << data.y << " " << data.z << " ";
}

// The read should be able to read the version printed using <<
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, MyClass& data)
{
    // Something like this
    // Be careful with strings.
    return str >> data.x >> data.y >> data.z;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass   plop;
    std::cout << plop;  // write to a file
    std::cin  >> plop;  // read from a file.


    std::vector<MyClass>  data;

    // Read a file with multiple objects into a vector.
    std::ifstream  loadFrom("plop");
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<MyClass>(loadFrom), std::istream_iterator<MyClass>(),
              std::back_inserter(data)
             );


    // Write a vector of objects to a file.
    std::ofstream   saveTo("Plip");
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<MyClass>(saveTo));

    // Note: The stream iterators (std::istream_iterator) and (std::ostream_iterator)
    //       are templatized on your type. They use the stream operators (operator>>)
    //       and (operator<<) to read from the stream.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this. I have seen serialization pop up a lot in my searches about this, but its always someone recommending the boost library. I really hate not knowing exactly whats going on under the hood so i'm avoiding using other libraries until i understand c++ better. I think now I'll be taking a good look at this code and some tutorials on serialization. Thanks again!

Comment: I suppose i should have mentioned this in my post, but i'm working with bitmaps and wave files. Would that change your answer or is serialization still the way to go?

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp: If you have specific file formats; then you need to follow the specification for those formats. You can not assume the memory lay out used by the compiler will match exactly to file format. So you will usually write each element specifically, which usually means that you have to write specific binary sizes (not sizeof(int)). You probably need to make sure things like integers are in network byte order (see specifications to be sure) see [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and family.

Comment: Yes I've found the specs for these files. The code i posted i started writing to read a bitmap file, and according to the spec I can count on the first 18 bytes to have the same info for any bitmap. Reading each element specifically seems to work fine like: [code]file.read ((char*)&bmp_id, 2); file.read ((char*)&bmp_size, 4);[/code], etc. Would serialization be any better than this? It keeps seeming overly complicated to me.

Comment: In this case serialization is **NOT** the technique you want.

Comment: So when IS serialization best? Why is it not what i want here?

Comment: It is usually the preferred technique. Because 1) It is human readable (thus easy to debug). 2) It is less brittle than a binary interface. 3) They are easy to write (and thus maintain). Binary interfaces are better: 1) If you have a well defined contract (it has to be very precise). 2) You have a large volume of data (or a large number of small items). **BUT** When designing code there is nothing stopping you from starting with one technique to get it going then swapping (apart from backwards compatibility with old data).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : there is no silver bullet to this problem.

One way you can eliminate the padding to ensure that the data members in your class is to use(in MSVC which you are using)

```
#pragma pack( push, 1 )

class YourClass {
    // your data members here
    int Data1;
    char Data2;
    // etc...
};

#pragma pack( pop )
```

The main usefulness of this approach is if your class matches a predefined format such as a bitmap header.  If it is a general purpose class to represent a cat, dog, whatever then dont use this approach.  Other thing if doing this is to make sure you know the length in bytes of the data types for your compiler, if your code is EVER going to be multi platform then you should use explicit sizes for the members such as __int32 etc.

If this is a general class, then in your save member, each value should be written explicitly.  A tip to do this is to create or get from sourceforge or somewhere good code to help do this.  Ideally, some code that allows the member to be named, I use something similar to :

```
SET_WRITE_DOUBLE( L"NameOfThing", DoubleMemberOfClass );
SET_WRITE_INT( L"NameOfThing2", IntMemberOfClass );
// and so on...
```

I created the code behind these macros, which I am not sharing for now but a clever person can create their own code to save named to stream in an unordered-set.  This I have found is the perfect approach because if you add or subtract data members to your class, the save/load is not dependent on the binary representation and order of your save, as your class will doubtless evolve through time if you save sequentially this is a problem you will face.

I hope this helps.